_variant_t unable to handle long numeric value
I am using ADO in C++ for MSSQL database operations.
One of my tables contains a numeric value.  The column is numeric(38,0).
When I try to get the  value in _variant_t, it throws an exception (code works if the value is small, like 5 or 6 digit).
DB MSSQL 2022, using Visual Studio 2022.
The exception is:
Error
        Code = 80040e21
        Description = Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Sample code:
string cmd = "SELECT* FROM [pubs].[dbo].[sample] ";
_CommandPtr pCmd = NULL;
_ConnectionPtr pConnection = NULL;
_RecordsetPtr rec = NULL;

try
{
    TESTHR(pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection)));
    TESTHR(pCmd.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command)));
    TESTHR(rec.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset)));

    FieldsPtr pFldLoop = NULL;

    pConnection->Open(strCnn, "", "", adConnectUnspecified);
    pCmd->PutRefActiveConnection(pConnection);
    pCmd->CommandText = cmd.c_str();
    rec = pCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText);
    pFldLoop = rec->GetFields();

    _variant_t index;
    index.vt = VT_I2;
    index.iVal = 0;

    _variant_t t1 = pFldLoop->GetItem(index)->GetValue(); //exception here 

    pConnection->Close();
}
catch (_com_error& e)
{
    PrintComError(e);
}


C++ doesn't haver a numeric type that supports 38 digits.  I would assume that's why you are getting an exception but I can't say for certain.

I don't think the issue is with the _variant_t, it looks like the exception is issuing prior to trying to assign the result.

ADO was designed for VB/VBA/VBSCript/JScript/etc and only works with VARIANT types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum, what used to be called "COM Automation data types"). No numeric VARIANT type can contain this. The biggest one is VT_DECIMAL which is 28 digits maximum (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ns-wtypes-decimal-r1). Or convert it to some binary representation before selecting it and do what you need with with binary representation. Or what exactly is this number that doesn't work?
